# Is it possible to get the primary key,Unique key and foreign key of a mysql table using Python?

Tags: python, mysql

Basically like connect to the MySQL DB and for the given table the script should return keys.

It is like a function that takes table name as the argument and returns the specified keys from the table.

ex:

```
def getKeys(tablename):

  Some code;
  return tablename.primaryKey,tablename.ForeignKey,tablename.uniqueKey
```

Comment: What sort of output do you expect when a table has a compound index?

Comment: Take a look at [the `information_schema` `table_constraints` table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/table-constraints-table.html).

Comment: It can return None.What i'm trying is to dynamically build the relationship between the tables.So with the help of these keys i believe We can build the shortest path between the tables dynamically.